# Curated data for sub-national entities (states and regions)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, regions

I am trying to find curated data on regions and states. For example, for Australia, I am trying to find government expenditure by state. The same with Canada (by region), and the USA.

Is there any curated data on this?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Have a look at [How to | Use Curated Data](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseCuratedData.html) and [CountryData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountryData.html)

Comment: Start by finding the entity of the region using `Interpreter["AdministrativeDivision"]["region name"]`. Then you can list categories of curated data using `regionEntity["Properties"]`. Finding out which of the entities actually work for your region is a process of trial and error. A property will return `Missing` if it doesn't exist for the given entity.